# GET/POST Request in Intel XDK implementation problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, intel, intel-xdk

I want to convert this jQuery code so that it can be used within Intel XDK.

**Code:**

```
lastRecord=0;
        function loadNews(){
            $('#sample').html( 'hello' );
            $.get( 
                "queryNews.php?lastRecord="+lastRecord,
            function( data ) {
                $('#news_mesgs').append( data )
                .listview( 'refresh' );
                    }
                );
            }
```

**Conversion:**

```
<script>
        var parameters = new AppMobi.Device.RemoteDataParameters();
        parameters.url = "http://i.cs.hku.hk/~hsbashir/Project_Work/Listview/queryNews.php";
        parameters.id = "12345";

        AppMobi.device.getRemoteDataExt(parameters);    

        var news = document.getElementById("news_mesgs");


        news.addEventListener("appMobi.device.remote.data",getRemoteDataEvent,false);
            var getRemoteDataEvent=function(event)
            {
                if(event.success==false)
                {
                alert("error obtaining remote data");    
                }
                else
                {
                alert("success: ");
                news.innerHTML += event.response;    
                }
            }    
        </script>
```

However, when i run my app in the emulator there is no alert seen or any thing.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you've assigned `getRemoteDataEvent` after using it, so when you use it in `news.addEventListener` it is `undefined`.  While function declarations are 'hoisted' within their  scope, and thus the order doesn't matter so much, when you create a function by assigning it to a variable as you did (a fine habit by the way), you need to do it in the proper order.

Try putting the `news.addEventListener(...)` line after then assugnment to getRemoteDataEvent and see if that changes things.